Attaching Rigid Aluminum Duct to Dryer
Changing flexible duct to rigid for dryer.
Everything is 4" round. Aluminum ducting and 90 degree swivel elbows from HD. The elbows fit into the duct coming out of the wall, but not to the outlet coming from the dryer. It's exactly the same size, so one can't go into the other.
Is this because my ducting is aluminum and the bit coming out of the dryer seems to be steel/galvanized?
Thanks!

Usually that tubing has male(plain) and female(crimped) ends.  So one fits into the other.  If two female or male ends meet together, you usually need an adapter to fit over.  Might be able to make one with aluminum duct tape(for furnace ducts) wrap around.  Pictures of the two ends will help.

@DIY75 stop being a troll. What a dumb comment.

@crip659 Yes. Coming out of the dryer is crimped. Coming out of the wall, is plain. So, crimped should always be going away from the dryer. The issue is that the crimped end coming from the dryer does not fit the "plain" end of the elbow. I'm wondering if it's an issue with galvanized/steel vs aluminum.

Maybe.  Sometimes a heavier squeeze is needed, or a simple snip(to squeeze more) of the end that goes in.

Use pliers to increase the degree of crimping on the dryer outlet to reduce the circumference. Pull the flex duct out to have a smooth surface if not already done so.

Multiple ways to approach this. I'd take a big worm-drive pipe clamp and put it on the end of the crimped section from the dryer, tighten it well, remove it, and see if we had squeezed it enough to now go into the uncrimped aluminum section.
If not, I'd consider taking a hammer to the aluminum section, but subtly. Just hammer evenly all around the open end of the duct, which should make the metal slightly thinner (and longer) and the duct opening slightly larger, more from the section of duct getting longer circumferentially than from the miniscule extent to which it will be thinner. You're not trying to put any dents in the metal, you're trying to stretch it just a bit. You'll need to work on an anvil horn or reasonable substitute, such as a piece of steel pipe.

If no anvil, a large exhaust pipe expander may work, e.g. https://www.homedepot.com/p/SKYSHALO-Pipe-Stretcher-Kit-Exhaust-Pipe-Stretcher-Kit-1-in-5-8-in-to-4-in-1-4-in-Exhaust-Pipe-Expander-Kit-for-Tail-JYLQQCXGJJT876AKDV0-0716/331792171

Yup, that would do it if you have access to one.
